# In NHibernate, is it possible to have a query return a mapped object that's partially filled with data (the rest being lazy loaded)?

Tags: nhibernate

In my legacy database, there is a giant table with 40+ columns. I would like to be able to partially fill my giant mapped class with data, so I'm only getting the data I need. How can I query nhibernate to return me my giant mapped object that has only the properties I want filled in?

Even better would be: If I do need another property that isn't filled in.. it would be lazily loaded.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Isaac

Comment: thanks for the input guys, I have to put this issue on hold for awhile while I solve some other problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to project the individual properties in your query. As far as I know, NHibernate doesn't allow you to lazy load individual properties.

Comment: does this return the object, or does it return some 2d array of results?

Comment: If you're using Query, you can select into a new object, if you're using HQL, Criteria, or QueryOver, you can use a Transform to get an alias class result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

http://ayende.com/blog/4377/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties

The byte code manipulator can be pretty powerful. According to this article only the Castle one supports it but it has been a year. I would *guess* Li supports it now.

And EVEN if that didn't work. It should be fairly straight forward to turn each property into it's own mapped-class in which the lazy loader would take affect. It's not ideal but it would be a work around if it didn't already support lazy properties. Luckily it appears NHibernate does.

Comment: Just a word of warning, eagerly fetching properties is only supported in HQL.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with Fluent NHibernate, so I assume it is with NHibernate. This code will work for FNH (and I am sorry, but I do not know the NHibernate equivalent, but if you know HBM files you should be able to work it out).

You have two ways of doing this, either load all as lazy by default, and then specify the properties you want to load fully separately, or the opposite where all properties are loaded by default and you specify those that you want to be lazy.

An example mapping for the first option (in FNH, again, sorry) would be something like this:

```
public partial class ActionableEventMap : SubclassMap<ActionableEvent>
{
    public ActionableEventMap()
    {
        References(x => x.Branch).Access.Property();
        References(x => x.Department).Access.Property();
        Map(x => x.Cost).Not.LazyLoad().Access.Property();
        Map(x => x.PurchaseOrderNumber).Not.LazyLoad().Access.Property();
        References(x => x.UserQualification).Access.Property();
    }
}
```

Note how you can specify the `lazy` property individually

Edit: actually, here's the hbm

```
<property access="property" name="LastReminder" type="System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" lazy="false">
  <column name="LastReminder" />
</property>
<property access="property" name="CCEmailString" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" lazy="false">
  <column name="CCEmailString" />
</property>
```

Comment: Does NH load up the individual properties as you access them or does it load all of the properties marked as lazy loaded as soon as one lazy loaded property is accessed?

Comment: load all when one is queried - figured the question only needed it for the initial loading\listing of objects. For individual DTO type queries Ayende's post that Andrew Finnell linked to would be the best solution.

Comment: That was my understanding as well. Just wanted to make sure I didn't miss something.